# source code of windows metro applications

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows-store-apps, directory

I like the look and feel of Bing News in Windows 8. So I have been wondering whether it is possible to take a look at the source code.
I know that some windows metro applications are written with HTML/CSS/JavaScript. So those files have to be stored somewhere in the computer. But where ? 
So far I have found a hidden file under `C:/Program Files` called `WindowsApps` but I cannot access it.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: "I know that all windows metro applications are written with HTML/CSS/JavaScript." Who told you that???

Comment: **some** metro apps are written in HTML/CSS/JavaScript... but not all. As for viewing the source, unless a developer chooses to show the source code, the published code should be locked away from prying eyes for security reasons. There's lots of sample code out there, just Google for the kind of task you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The hidden folder WindowsApps has the packages for the apps that you are looking for. You can then use a tool like dotPeek to view the decompiled source code. Most of the apps however are written in HTML/Javascript
https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

Answer (score 0):

You need to change that owner of that folder. Similar question:

[How to get access to C:\Program Files\WindowsApps in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/498774/how-to-get-access-to-c-program-files-windowsapps-in-windows-8)